# reducir tiempo de importarcion archivo plano con django

Tags: python, django

Saludos estoy importando un archivo plano con Django el cual tiene un total de "**217732**" filas, cada fila tiene 22 columnas, las mismas las lee bien e insertar en una tabla, le problema surge en el tiempo esta cantidad de informacion tarda 10 minutos lo cual es excesivo para esperar quiza alguna sugerencias de como cargar dicha informacion y mejorar tiempos, adjunto codigo:

```
   import os
    catastro = request.FILES['catastro']
    #subir archivo
    fs = FileSystemStorage()
    filename = fs.save(catastro.name, catastro)
    uploaded_file_url = fs.url(filename)
    #leer archivo
    import csv
    from django.conf import settings
    import datetime
    with open(os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, catastro.name), 'rb') as csvfile:
        reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, delimiter='\t')
        for row in reader:
            with transaction.atomic():
                fia = datetime.datetime.strptime(row['FECHA_INICIO_ACTIVIDADES'], "%d/%m/%Y").strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
                if row['FECHA_ACTUALIZACION']:
                    fa = datetime.datetime.strptime(row['FECHA_ACTUALIZACION'], "%d/%m/%Y").strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
                else:
                    fa = None

                if row['FECHA_SUSPENSION_DEFINITIVA']:
                    fsd = datetime.datetime.strptime(row['FECHA_SUSPENSION_DEFINITIVA'], "%d/%m/%Y").strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
                else:
                    fsd = None

                if row['FECHA_REINICIO_ACTIVIDADES']:
                    fra = datetime.datetime.strptime(row['FECHA_REINICIO_ACTIVIDADES'], "%d/%m/%Y").strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
                else:
                    fra = None
                c = CatastroSri(
                    NUMERO_RUC=row['NUMERO_RUC'],
                    RAZON_SOCIAL = row['RAZON_SOCIAL'],
                    NOMBRE_COMERCIAL = row['NOMBRE_COMERCIAL'],
                    ESTADO_CONTRIBUYENTE = row['ESTADO_CONTRIBUYENTE'],
                    CLASE_CONTRIBUYENTE = row['CLASE_CONTRIBUYENTE'],
                    FECHA_INICIO_ACTIVIDADES = fia,
                    FECHA_ACTUALIZACION = fa,
                    FECHA_SUSPENSION_DEFINITIVA = fsd,
                    FECHA_REINICIO_ACTIVIDADES = fra,
                    OBLIGADO = row['OBLIGADO'],
                    TIPO_CONTRIBUYENTE = row['TIPO_CONTRIBUYENTE'],
                    NUMERO_ESTABLECIMIENTO = row['NUMERO_ESTABLECIMIENTO'],
                    NOMBRE_FANTASIA_COMERCIAL = row['NOMBRE_FANTASIA_COMERCIAL'],
                    CALLE = row['CALLE'],
                    NUMERO = row['NUMERO'],
                    INTERSECCION = row['INTERSECCION'],
                    ESTADO_ESTABLECIMIENTO = row['ESTADO_ESTABLECIMIENTO'],
                    DESCRIPCION_PROVINCIA = row['DESCRIPCION_PROVINCIA'],
                    DESCRIPCION_CANTON = row['DESCRIPCION_CANTON'],
                    DESCRIPCION_PARROQUIA = row['DESCRIPCION_PARROQUIA'],
                    CODIGO_CIIU = row['CODIGO_CIIU'],
                    ACTIVIDAD_ECONOMICA = row['ACTIVIDAD_ECONOMICA'],
                )
                c.save()
```

gracias por cualquier sugerencia.